# Deployed web on Azure cannot access a .less file (error code 404). Local IIS deployment works without error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015, less

I deployed a website in https://pokegotool.azurewebsites.net.

However, when I use a browser to access it and read the browser console, it told that the "Content/pre-css/styles.less" file is inaccessible (error code 404).

I build the web site locally in IIS and it had no such problem as the file is loaded successfully. I am sure that the file exists in Azure deployment place.

This URL is ZIP archived project: https://www.mediafire.com/file/i6745pz5j43cw2z/RangeGen.zip/file

Feel free to use it.

Is this an error from Azure or from my project itself? How could I fix it?

Comment: Well shouldn't you compile less into css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed your project and met the same issue . Basically , it is due to that Azure app service IIS server have not mapped correct MIME type for .less files by default.

To solve this issue , just adding a map record in your web.config file as below :
[image]

```
 <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/plain" />
     </staticContent>
 </system.webServer>
```

It works on my app service , try it here : https://rangegen20190902101335.azurewebsites.net/Content/pre-css/styles.less

Pls mark me if it solves your issue : )

Comment: You are my savior. Thank you.

Comment: @leanhluudan It is my pleasure ! Pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to make my answer . Thanks you !